# Creating a release build with Ant not outputing all files?

Tags: apache-flex, ant, flex4

I'm trying to create an Ant task to create a release build but it only outputs one SWF file and that SWF file size is smaller than normal and it doesn't output all the normal files from a normal Flash Builder release build such as history folder, project assets, the SDK RSLs and so on.

```
<!-- Build and output the Avenue.swf--> 
<target name="compileFlex" depends="init,compileLib1,compileLib2">
    <mxmlc file="${APP_SRC}/app.mxml" output="output/app.swf">
        <load-config filename="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/flex-config.xml"/> 
        <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/> 
        <include-libraries file="${LIB1_SWC}" append="true"/>
        <include-libraries file="${LIB2_SWC}" append="true"/>
    </mxmlc> 
</target>
```

It creates one SWF and nothing else.

Here's part of the output:

```
[mxmlc] Required RSLs:
[mxmlc]     http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.5.1.21328/framework_4.5.1.21489.swz with 1 failover.
[mxmlc]     http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/tlf/2.0.0.232/textLayout_2.0.0.232.swz with 1 failover.
[mxmlc]     http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.5.1.21328/spark_4.5.1.21489.swz with 1 failover.
[mxmlc]     http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.5.1.21328/sparkskins_4.5.1.21328.swz with 1 failover.
[mxmlc]     http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.5.1.21328/rpc_4.5.1.21328.swz with 1 failover.
[mxmlc]     http://fpdownload.adobe.com/pub/swz/flex/4.5.1.21328/mx_4.5.1.21489.swz with 1 failover.

[mxmlc] /Users/.../output/app.swf (698490 bytes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mxmlc task only compiles flex modules.  You have to manage the history folder and project assets separately.  A task that will get you partway there is the html-wrapper task, which generates an html wrapper from an html template.

Comment: I figured it as much. I ended up coming up with a script that copies the files that it is missing.

Comment: I ended up using the <runtime-shared-library-path> element to deal with all my rsls, and writing a wrapper creator script based on this guy's [work](http://ruprict.net/2009/08/04/continuous-integration-with-flex-hudson-and-arcgis-server-part-2/)

The advantage is that I got to keep my custom template.  The disadvantage is that I have to manually copy all my stuff and use regexes to fill in the template.  You sound like you've got it figured out long ago, so I'm mostly giving background that I found useful when wrangling a similar problem